# Who was the youngest player to win an ATP World Tour tournament

Tags: trivia, tennis, records, atp

I was trying to find the information about youngest player with [ATP World Tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_ATP_World_Tour) title.

I found on Wikipedia that [Michael Chang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Chang) is the youngest player to win Grand Slam title. Wikipedia also has [list of oldest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Era_tennis_records_%E2%80%93_men%27s_singles#Miscellaneous) tournament winners ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Open_Era_tennis_records_%E2%80%93_men%27s_singles&oldid=729270338#Miscellaneous)). But I did not find information about who was the youngest tournament winner.

Comment: The Wikipedia article linked in the question now also [lists the youngest tournament winners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Era_tennis_records_%E2%80%93_men%27s_singles#Miscellaneous) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Open_Era_tennis_records_%E2%80%93_men%27s_singles&oldid=1004566027#Miscellaneous)),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean any ATP tournament (and not the overall Finals), [Aaron Krickstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Krickstein) won an ATP World Tour tournament in Tel Aviv in 1983 at the age of 16 years 2 months, the youngest to do so according to his wikipedia page (which cites a book with that information).  I don't see any other source that disagrees, and he's still listed in Wikipedia as the youngest top 10 in the ATP rankings, so that seems likely.